# Series looping into itself

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We start with $2$ digits.
Each step we look at the last 2 digits and append their multiplication to the series.

So if the numbers are $1$ and $2$

$1 \times 2=2,~~~
2 \times 2=4,~~~
2 \times 4=8,~~~
4 \times 8=32,~~~
3 \times 2=6,~~~
2 \times 6=12$

$\{\mathbf{1,2},2,4,8,3,2,6,\mathbf{1,2}\}$

So the series again starts with 1, 2.

For $1$ and $3$,
$\{1, 3, 3, 9, 2, 7, 1, 4, 4, 1, 6, 6, 3, 6, 1, 8, 8, 6, 4, \mathbf{2, 4}, 8, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, \mathbf{2, 4}\}$

If I take any other two digit combination, it always loops (not always to the beginning though). How do we prove that it always loops?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model each state as $(x,y)$ where $(x , y) \in \{0,\ldots,  9\}^2$.

Each state either point to another state or itself, since it is finite (in your case there are $100$ states), eventually, you will visit a state that you have visited before, a loop can be observed starting from there.

For your first example, the states are

$$(1,2) \to (2,4) \to (4,8) \to (3,2) \to (2,6) \to (1,2)$$

We can repeat the argument to more digits as well.